# NVidia drivers screen freeze with ASUS TUF

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, freeze

[[image]

I have a problem: occasionally, my system freezes.

I bought an Asus TUF Gaming F15 gaming laptop with RTX 2050 and an Intel Core i5 11th generation processor and the system freezes.

For example, I'm talking to a friend via Discord, I can still hear him, I can move the mouse, the image moves, but nothing else. I can do it, I looked for the answer, but I couldn't find it.

Sorry for the language, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS .

> [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]]
> *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

What may be the problem?